# Matching correctly two polygons that come from different shapefiles

Tags: python, geopandas, shapely, topojson, fiona

I am trying to match 2 polygons that come from two different shapefiles,
The one with the borders (black line) and the one with blue color in the picture.
[image: see here].
My main point is how I can match them correctly and avoid the exceeding areas that are outside the black borders and the areas that are inside with holes ?

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: Are you sure those two are supposed to match? Usually, such a problem comes from having different CRS for each shapefile, but here it looks like the blue areas are defined with more precision than your border.